# How to access UITableViewCell's UITextView from the UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I have created my own UITableViewCell with XIB file. There's an UITextView inside. However, I don't know how to access its features and use its outlets with the UIViewController. What's the way to do it?

[alt text http://cl.ly/a13e180c260e5e550b78/content](http://cl.ly/a13e180c260e5e550b78/content)

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by pulling the subview out of the cell's `subviews` array and casting it to `UITextView`:

How you created your view hierarchy will determine the index to pass to `objectAtIndex`.

`UITextView *textView = (UITextView*) [cell.subviews objectAtIndex:whateverIndex];`